# ReactJS throws exception on simple JSX text

Tags: reactjs

I am currently facing this error:

```
Line 14:11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

My code looks this way:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "./Checkbox";

export const Tasks = () => {
  const tasks = [];
  let projectName = "";

  return (
    <div className="tasks" data-testid="tasks">
      <h2 data-testid="project-name">{projectName}</h2>

      <ul className="tasks__list">
        {tasks.map(task => {
          <li key={task.id}>
            <Checkbox id={task.id} />
            <span>{task.task}</span>
          </li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

According to the error, the problem occurs on the line `<li key={task.id}>`. I read other posts related to this error but couldn't fix it.

Comment: You don't return from the map callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is a typo but it seems that you forgot to `return` inside your map callback:

```
tasks.map(task => {
          return (<li key={task.id}>
            <Checkbox id={task.id} />
            <span>{task.task}</span>
          </li>);
        })
```

**Edit**

As a followup to your comment, arrow functions can return implicitly when there is no body (i.e `{}`):

```
() => 'the returned value'
```

Or multiline returned expression:

```
() => (
 <div>
  hi
 </div>
)
```

Comment: Not a typo. Just following tutorial and that's what I saw :) But after closer look I saw that instead of `task => {` the tutor use `taks => (`. So I guess `task => (` is the same as `task => { return ( ...`?

Comment: Yes. If you omit curly braces, you can only return one expression from fat-arrow function (function with `=>`). In your case, that expression is your `li` node wrapped by parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `li` node into parentheses and return it like so:

```
{tasks.map(task => {
 return (
   <li key={task.id}>
       <Checkbox id={task.id} />
       <span>{task.task}</span>
   </li>
 );        
})}
```